# Ordinal + Continuous interaction in lavaan

Tags: interaction, ordinal, r-lavaan

I'm completing a moderation mediation analysis in lavaan.

All of my variables are continuous other than my mediator, which is an ordinal with 3 levels (0,1,2). Lavaan can't handle interactions between ordinal and continuous variables, so I am troubleshooting the best way around this.

Some folks have suggested treating my ordered variable as pseudocontinuous, however with only 3 levels, I'm worried I'll get push back from reviewers. I could create the interaction term between the ordinal variable (but treated as continuous here) and the continuous outside of the model and then use it as a variable in the model while keeping the ordinal variable itself as ordered in the model.

Is there anything wrong with doing this? Any other suggestions?

```
data$int <- data$ordinal_cont * data$continuous
data[, "ordinal"] <- lapply(data["ordinal"], ordered)

model -> `
L1 =~ X1 + X2 + X3 
L2 =~ Z1 + Z2 + Z3

L1 ~ a*L2 + c*Continuous + d*Ordinal + e*int
ordinal ~ b*L2

ab := a*b 

L2 ~~ Continuous
L2 ~~ ordinal
Continuous ~~ ordinal
`
fit <- sem(model,
            se = "bootstrap",
            bootstrap = 2000,
            data = data,
            parallel = "snow",
            ncpus = 8,
            ordered = "pubertal_onset",
            estimator = "DWLS")
```

Thanks,

Clare

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything wrong with doing this?

Yes, the interpretations would not match:

- the simple effect of `Ordinal` would be on the continuous latent-response scale
- the degree to which it is moderated by `continuous` would be on the observed discrete-response scale

The observed and latent responses don't share locations or scales, so you wouldn't actually be testing/interpreting an interaction effect.

> Any other suggestions?

A tedious, time-consuming, but very flexible option would be parameter moderation (often called moderated nonlinear factor analysis (MNLFA), but it is really more general than that).  That is not available in `lavaan`, but it is available in the `OpenMx` package:

Kolbe, L., Molenaar, D., Jak, S., & Jorgensen, T. D. (2022). Assessing measurement invariance with moderated nonlinear factor analysis using the R package `OpenMx`. *Psychological Methods*. https://doi.org/10.1037/met0000501

The tutorial is about testing invariance (which you should consider testing for your 2 common factors, one of which you consider to be affected by `Ordinal` and by `continuou`).  However, you can fit any kind of SEM (in your case, a simple mediation model at the structural level: `L2` --> `Ordinal` --> `L1`) and have any model parameters (including variances) moderated by `continuous`.